# Tensorflow-gpu Windows 10 import issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

After considerable amount of diligence I am not able to resolve this issue. So basically I had tensorflow 1.8 running perfectly on my win 10 with CUDA 9 and cudnn 7.0. I wanted to check if support for CUDA 9.2 was added in tf 1.10.0

I installed cuda 9.2 and then tf 1.10.0 along with cudnn 7.2 and learned that support was not added.

Tried to go back to my original configuration and I am unable to do so. Here are some points:

- This is not and AVX issue as my CPU supports AVX (i5) and my GPU is 1080 Ti
- This configuration was working just fine before without hitches, so the issue seems to be uninstall/reinstall related
- Install goes smoothly and error shows up when importing. Error is "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found"
- Environment variables are not the issue as they are correctly set
- I uninstalled every piece of CUDA/graphic driver related software, deleted all remaining files, restarted, reinstalled, restarted and then tried again to no use

I have read all similar threads and common issues are all the ones above that I have already looked into. So please read this post before you rush to mark duplicate. Any suggestions on how to get this to work are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I just installed the GPU version (which upgraded TF to 1.10 from 1.8) and I get the DLL load failed error. I suspect that there is a problem with 1.10

Comment: I refreshed my windows and then this guide here worked to install 1.10. Note I couldn't get it to work without a windows reinstall. https://github.com/rohit-patel/Install_Instructions-Win10-Deeplearning-Keras-Tensorflow